# I got error when passing a parameterised class in system verilog instance

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

i tried to make an instance of this  module it gave me the following error (unexpected '#', expecting class.).
why ?
what is the solution?
[here is the module,instance and the error in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSRs4.png)

Comment: Please, error messages are there for a reason. it points you to the file and to the line number. you should have been able to spot the syntax issue immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You used `#include` instead of `` `include ``

Answer (score -1):

In pulp_2.v file, change `#include` by `'include`